# Offsetting polygon using Boost.Geometry?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

The [Boost Polygon library states](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/polygon/doc/index.htm) that it is possible to offset polygons(symmetrically ).But I haven't found any method in the API or  example of how to do it .Anyone can confirm that Boost geometry can do it?  Also I have found this question :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668331/outline-of-a-polygon-in-boost
Which seems to be asking the similar question. Please keep in mind that libs like [Polygon Clipper](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php) can do it wonderfully but my point of interest in Boost is that it is fast and it supports floats.
Thanks for help.

UPDATE: I am talking about both Boost geometry and polygons library because I am not sure which one contains or lacks this feature.

Comment: Are you talking about the polygon library or the geometry library?  You use both words.  The geometry library has the algorithm `buffer` which may be what you mean by "offset".  If not, please clarify.

Comment: Yes ,you are right. In fact I don't know which one is correct because I found no info or example of the usage.

Comment: Let me rephrase.  What do you mean by "symmetrically offset"?

Comment: I mean that the offset distance from any point on the polygon edge is the same. In other words under "offset" I mean outline :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using boost geometry, the function you want is called `buffer`.  From the docs:

> buffer
>
> Calculates the buffer of a geometry.
>
> Description
>
> The free function buffer calculates the buffer (a polygon being the
>   spatial point set collection within a specified maximum distance from
>   a geometry) of a geometry.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms.html

Comment: Thanks guys ,how have I missed it ?! Probably because of the method "intuitive" name :) @n.m and Peter -would give you both green mark but the system doesn't allow ;)

Comment: @Peter This doesn't seem to be implemented for boost::geometry::model::polygon ? See http://ideone.com/vg1PIE

Answer (score 5):

According to the boost doc:
[Boost buffer algorithm](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/buffer/buffer.html)
This is not currently available for general polygons:
"The current implemetation only enlarges a box, which is not defined by OGC. A next version of the library will contain a more complete implementation"

Answer (score 2):

The relevant functions are `resize` and its variants `bloat` and `shrink`.

Comment: Also worth noting that the `+=` operator is overloaded for this purpose too (although not obvious from the documentation).